# Seeking Guidance on Retrieving Data from Google Ads API

Tags: google-ads-api

I am reaching out to seek guidance as I am currently facing challenges with retrieving data from the Google Ads API. I have followed the official guide at https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/get-started/introduction, and while I have a developer token, a Google API Console project, and a Google Ads account, I am struggling to understand how to effectively utilize the client library.
As a newcomer to Google Ads, I am seeking assistance on the best practices and an easy way to get started with fetching data from the Google Ads API. If anyone in the community has experience with this process or could provide step-by-step guidance, I would greatly appreciate your support.
Here are some specific points I'm looking for assistance with:

Understanding how to use the developer token and integrate it with the API.
Utilizing the client library effectively for retrieving data.
Any simplified examples or guidance for someone new to Google Ads.

I have posted the same issue on **Google Ads API and AdWords API Forum**, it has been many days I didn't get any response. So I am here for some suggestions, tips, and any resources that may aid me in overcoming this learning curve. Your expertise and guidance will be immensely valuable in helping me navigate through this process.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance. Looking forward to learning and growing with the support of this wonderful community.

Trying to get the ctr from google ads api but unable to handle the api request as an absolute beginner.